# how to know which link was clicked(if it is same for every row) and parse data for that row

Tags: jquery, html

i have a table with a lot of stuff, i need to parse it row and send data to server.

```
<td class="itt_text-left" title="Standart Room">Std</td>

<td class="text-center" title="HB">HB</td>

<td class="text-center">6</td>
<a name="modal" href="#dialog">advanced</a>
```

link advanced is same for every row, but data is different.
i need to know which link is clicked and parse it row(every td) into an array(or something) to send it via ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `this` keyword is what you want to do. This code:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var $trow = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

will create a variable `$trow` which is a jQuery object containing the entire `<tr>`.

You can then parse or manipulate it however you like inside that `click` handler. For instance:

```
    var str1 = $trow.find('td').eq(0).text(); // first cell, zero-indexed
    var str2 = $trow.find('td').eq(1).text(); // second cell
```